# Sistema tipo do youtube?

Tags: javascript

Como se faz aquele sistema estilo o youtube que o vídeo só começa a rodar quando a página está focada.

Tipo, se você abrir a página em uma nova aba e não clicar nela a página vai carregar mas o vídeo não vai "rodar", somente se eu clicar na aba que ele começa a funcionar, como se faz isso ?

Comment: window.focus() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apesar da pergunta ser um pouco vaga, recomendo que use funções `JavaScript`, como [`window.focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus), para realizar a tarefa.

Te recomendo ler um pouco sobre a manipulação de [mídia com API's do JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Capabilities_API) e sobre [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_htmldom.asp), além de definir exatamente o que seu programa vai fazer...

Bons estudos ;)